# Calling method of base class in inheritance chanin in Lua

Tags: inheritance, lua

This is a question about calling method shared by a class and its base class, and the base class of its base class.

This is the code sample

```lua
local Base = {} -- inheriting root
Base.base = nil -- base class of current class

function Base:New()
    self.__index = self
    return setmetatable({}, self)
end

---------------------------
local Person = setmetatable({}, Base)
Person.base = Base

function Person:New()
    local this = self.base.New(self)
    -- ...
    return this
end


---------------------------
local Student = setmetatable({}, Person)
Student.base = Person

function Student:New()
    local this = self.base.New(self)
    -- ...
    return this
end
```

If I do `local s = Student:New()`, I will run into an infinite recursion. Caused by `self.base.New(self)`.

`self.base.New` is `New` method of `Person`, now with local `self` set to `Student` class table. And will again, call `self.base.New(self)`. And this goes infinitely.

In the case of constructor, that self is unnecessary, and can be replaced by

```lua
self.__index = self
local this = setmetatable(self.base:New(), self)
```

But its actually needed some times. For example,

```lua
Foo = { a = false }
Foo.__index = Foo
function Foo:CleanUp()
    if not self.a then self.a = true end
end

Bar = setmetatable({ base = Foo, a = false, b = false }, Foo)
Bar.__index = Bar
function Bar:CleanUp()
    self.base:CleanUp()
    if not self.b then self.b = true end
end

local bar = setmetatable({}, Bar)
bar:CleanUp()
print(bar.a)
print(bar.base.a)
```

`CleanUp` simply make boolean fields become `true`, and after running `bar:ClearUp()`, `bar.a` is still `false`, because we do `self.base:CleanUp()`.

So how can I improve it? How can I still call the method from base class but avoid infinite recursion at the same time?

My current solution is to separate each class into standalone file, and do this:

```lua
local Super = require "Person"
-- ...

function Student:New()
    local this = Super.New(self)
    -- ...
end
```

Comment: you don't need a separate file per class to do the last one

Comment: @user253751 I do know `Person.New(self)` will work too, but I tend to think it's error-prone. Say I want to change `Student` to inherit from `Kid`, which is a subclass of `Person`. I'm pretty sure that I won't be enjoying changing each `Person` method call into `Kid` method call. With `require` I need only to change one line of code. So, any suggestion about this?

Comment: You don't need `require` to use that technique. You can put `local Super = Person` right before each class definition. (Substitute `Person` for whatever the base class is.) If you use `local` each time (instead of just reassigning), each class will see a different `Super` variable, and you won't have to worry about `Super` always being equal to its last assignment. That will allow you to put multiple classes in one file.

Comment: @luther you can also use `do ... end` blocks to add scopes for local variables

Comment: @user253751 OK, that is really nice, thanks.